# imacros, I'm trying to pull the name of an image file from a web page

Tags: javascript, imacros

Here is the code:

```
<div class="section">
<div class="headingBox">
<table><td class="profileLeft"><img     src="http://static.MyUrl.com/myPlace/images/type/1_60x33.png?v=30">
</td>
<td>other stuff here<td>
</td>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

I need to pull the name of the image file to evaluate then make further code to decide what to do?

My code pulls a blank?

```
var macro1 = "CODE: "
macro1+= "TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:headingBox" +"\n"
macro1+= "TAG POS=1 TYPE=TD ATTR=CLASS:profileLeft"+"\n"
macro1+= "TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:* EXTRACT=TXT"+"\n"
iimplay(macro1)
var ImgName=iimGetLastExtract()
window.alert(ImgName)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Is **EXTRACT=TXT"\n"** missing "**+**" -> **EXTRACT=TXT"+"\n"** ?

Comment: Yes, it is here but not in the code, sorry, typo from my iPad!

Comment: Typo fixed, wish I could give a screenshot

Comment: unfortunately, the developer of the website did not use alt tags, and is using a picture only to represent the country. So I must determine which picture they are using then further program to determine which country....

Comment: Extract 'HREF' but not 'TXT':  `TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:* EXTRACT=HREF`

Answer (score 0):

EXTRACT=HREF could work but I am not sure.

You can use EXTRACT=HTM

and `text=text.split('src:"')[1].split('">')[0];`

This could get the SRC code.